# TF2 Keras - Feature Engineering in Keras saved model via Tensorflow Serving

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving, feature-engineering

The Tensorflow 2 documentation for preprocessing / feature engineering over a Keras model seems to be quite confusing and isn't very friendly.

Currently I have a simple Keras N-layer model with TF feature columns feeding as dense layer. For training I have CSV files read using `tf.dataset` API and I have written a feature engineering function that creates new features using `dataset.map` function.

```
def feature_engg_features(features):
  #Add new features
  features['nodlgrbyvpatd'] = features['NODLGR'] / features['VPATD']

  return(features)
```

I can save the model easily using `tf.keras.models.save_model` method. However I am having trouble figuring out how to attach the `feature_engineering` steps in the serving function.

**Requirement**: Now I want to take the same feature engineering function above and attach it to my `serving function` so that in JSON input via `tensorflow_model_server` the same feature engineering steps are applied. I know about the lambda Layer option in Keras but I want to do this via `saved_model` method but there are a lot of difficulties here.

For Example, below code gives error:

```
def feature_engg_features(features):
  #Add new features
  features['nodlgrbyvpatd'] = features['NODLGR'] / features['VPATD']
  return(features)

@tf.function
def serving(data):
    data = tf.map_fn(feature_engg_features, data, dtype=tf.float32)

    # Predict
    predictions = m_(data)

version = "1"
tf.keras.models.save_model(
    m_,
    "./exported_model/" + version,
    overwrite=True,
    include_optimizer=True,
    save_format=None,
    signatures=serving,
    options=None
)
```

Error:

```
Only `tf.functions` with an input signature or concrete functions can be used as a signature.
```

The above error is because I have not provided InputSignature of my Keras model but I am not able to understand that I have 13 input fields, what is expected as input signature.

So I wanted to know if anyone knows the shortest way of solving this out. This is a very basic requirement and Tensorflow seems to have kept this quite complicated for Keras Tensorflow model serving.

GIST: https://colab.research.google.com/gist/rafiqhasan/6abe93ac454e942317005febef59a459/copy-of-dl-e2e-structured-mixed-data-tf-2-keras-estimator.ipynb

**EDIT:**
I fixed it, so TensorSpec has to be generated and passed for each feature and also model( ) has to be called in serving function.

```
@tf.function
def serving(WERKS, DIFGRIRD, SCENARIO, TOTIRQTY, VSTATU, EKGRP, TOTGRQTY, VPATD, EKORG, NODLGR, DIFGRIRV, NODLIR, KTOKK):
    ##Feature engineering
    nodlgrbyvpatd = tf.cast(NODLGR / VPATD, tf.float32)

    payload = {
        'WERKS': WERKS,
        'DIFGRIRD': DIFGRIRD,
        'SCENARIO': SCENARIO,
        'TOTIRQTY': TOTIRQTY,
        'VSTATU': VSTATU,
        'EKGRP': EKGRP,
        'TOTGRQTY': TOTGRQTY,
        'VPATD': VPATD,
        'EKORG': EKORG,
        'NODLGR': NODLGR,
        'DIFGRIRV': DIFGRIRV,
        'NODLIR': NODLIR,
        'KTOKK': KTOKK,
        'nodlgrbyvpatd': nodlgrbyvpatd,        
    }

    ## Predict
    ##IF THERE IS AN ERROR IN NUMBER OF PARAMS PASSED HERE OR DATA TYPE THEN IT GIVES ERROR, "COULDN'T COMPUTE OUTPUT TENSOR"
    predictions = m_(payload)
    return predictions

serving = serving.get_concrete_function(WERKS=tf.TensorSpec([None,], dtype= tf.string, name='WERKS'), 
                                        DIFGRIRD=tf.TensorSpec([None,], name='DIFGRIRD'),
                                        SCENARIO=tf.TensorSpec([None,], dtype= tf.string, name='SCENARIO'), 
                                        TOTIRQTY=tf.TensorSpec([None,], name='TOTIRQTY'),
                                        VSTATU=tf.TensorSpec([None,], dtype= tf.string, name='VSTATU'), 
                                        EKGRP=tf.TensorSpec([None,], dtype= tf.string, name='EKGRP'),
                                        TOTGRQTY=tf.TensorSpec([None,], name='TOTGRQTY'), 
                                        VPATD=tf.TensorSpec([None,], name='VPATD'),
                                        EKORG=tf.TensorSpec([None,], dtype= tf.string, name='EKORG'), 
                                        NODLGR=tf.TensorSpec([None,], name='NODLGR'),
                                        DIFGRIRV=tf.TensorSpec([None,], name='DIFGRIRV'),
                                        NODLIR=tf.TensorSpec([None,], name='NODLIR'),
                                        KTOKK=tf.TensorSpec([None,], dtype= tf.string, name='KTOKK')
                                        )

version = "1"
tf.saved_model.save(
    m_,
    "./exported_model/" + version,
    signatures=serving
)
```

Answer (score 1):

So the right way to do this is here, Feature engineering and Pre-processing can be done in the `serving_default` method through below option. I tested it further via Tensorflow serving.

```
@tf.function
def serving(WERKS, DIFGRIRD, SCENARIO, TOTIRQTY, VSTATU, EKGRP, TOTGRQTY, VPATD, EKORG, NODLGR, DIFGRIRV, NODLIR, KTOKK):
    ##Feature engineering
    nodlgrbyvpatd = tf.cast(NODLGR / VPATD, tf.float32)

    payload = {
        'WERKS': WERKS,
        'DIFGRIRD': DIFGRIRD,
        'SCENARIO': SCENARIO,
        'TOTIRQTY': TOTIRQTY,
        'VSTATU': VSTATU,
        'EKGRP': EKGRP,
        'TOTGRQTY': TOTGRQTY,
        'VPATD': VPATD,
        'EKORG': EKORG,
        'NODLGR': NODLGR,
        'DIFGRIRV': DIFGRIRV,
        'NODLIR': NODLIR,
        'KTOKK': KTOKK,
        'nodlgrbyvpatd': nodlgrbyvpatd,        
    }

    ## Predict
    ##IF THERE IS AN ERROR IN NUMBER OF PARAMS PASSED HERE OR DATA TYPE THEN IT GIVES ERROR, "COULDN'T COMPUTE OUTPUT TENSOR"
    predictions = m_(payload)
    return predictions

serving = serving.get_concrete_function(WERKS=tf.TensorSpec([None,], dtype= tf.string, name='WERKS'), 
                                        DIFGRIRD=tf.TensorSpec([None,], name='DIFGRIRD'),
                                        SCENARIO=tf.TensorSpec([None,], dtype= tf.string, name='SCENARIO'), 
                                        TOTIRQTY=tf.TensorSpec([None,], name='TOTIRQTY'),
                                        VSTATU=tf.TensorSpec([None,], dtype= tf.string, name='VSTATU'), 
                                        EKGRP=tf.TensorSpec([None,], dtype= tf.string, name='EKGRP'),
                                        TOTGRQTY=tf.TensorSpec([None,], name='TOTGRQTY'), 
                                        VPATD=tf.TensorSpec([None,], name='VPATD'),
                                        EKORG=tf.TensorSpec([None,], dtype= tf.string, name='EKORG'), 
                                        NODLGR=tf.TensorSpec([None,], name='NODLGR'),
                                        DIFGRIRV=tf.TensorSpec([None,], name='DIFGRIRV'),
                                        NODLIR=tf.TensorSpec([None,], name='NODLIR'),
                                        KTOKK=tf.TensorSpec([None,], dtype= tf.string, name='KTOKK')
                                        )

version = "1"
tf.saved_model.save(
    m_,
    "./exported_model/" + version,
    signatures=serving
)
```